# When using frontity, the source code is changed in the editor, and the browser displays the original content

Tags: reactjs, frontity

I encountered a problem when using frontity, the code was updated, but the console did not respond, and the page in the browser would not change accordingly, too. I had to delete the node_modules directory and execute yarn to generate this directory, so that the browsing page would change accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your package is a local package, rather than in the node_modules directory. A similar issue came up in the Frontity Community Forum: https://community.frontity.org/t/code-changed-but-the-console-do-not-take-any-response/4459